# Is it a bad idea to have components as public static variables in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Like this:

```
export class MyComponent{
    public static mycomponent:MyComponent;
    constructor() {
        MyComponent.mycomponent = this;
    }
}
```

and in some other component or service:

```
MyComponent.mycomponent.dostuff();
```

Comment: What is the point of it?

Comment: just come code I threw toghether for a meeting because I didn't have time to use a service to communicate between 2 components... I was asking because it looks a lot easier than using a service

Comment: yes it's bad idea and anti-pattern, do not use this method of handling communications between two components.